# How can I draw angled lines in LaTeX to create ruled template for calligraphy?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, line-spacing, coordinates, tikz-angles

I am trying to create a template for calligraphy writing. I would like it to look something like this picture below, but with no margins nor title (A4 paper). I want to have three types of lines:

1. Horizontal lines alternating every 1 cm, dark black color.
2. Horizontal lines alternating every 0.5 cm, light gray color. They will basically be in between the black 1 cm lines.
3. Lines at an angle of 55 degrees alternating every 1 cm, red color. It would also be nice if that angle is a variable so that I can change it later if needed.

   [image]

---

This is what I was able to do so far, but since I am drawing lines based on a rectangular coordinate system, I do not know how to adjust the angle of the sloped lines to be 55 degrees. I basically only need to fix that; otherwise, I am satisfied with my outcome.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article} %do not include "draft" in order to render pictures
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]

\foreach \i in {1,2,3,...,30}{
    \draw[black] ($(current page.north west)+(0,-\i)$) -- ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\i)$);}

\foreach \i in {0.5,1.5,2.5,...,60}{
    \draw[lightgray] ($(current page.north west)+(0,-\i)$) -- ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\i)$);}

\foreach \i in {1,2,3,...,60}{
    \draw[red] ($(current page.south west)+(0,-\i)$) -- ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\i)$);}

\foreach \i in {0,1,2,3,...,60}{
    \draw[red] ($(current page.south west)+(0,+\i)$) -- ($(current page.north east)+(0,+\i)$);}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This is my output.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You say you want this on A4 paper but use `\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}`, why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use polar coordinates such as `(55:100cm)`. In the code below, I compute the precise number of oblique lines to draw in function of the chosen angle `\myAngle` and the distance `\myDist` between two consecutive oblique lines. My code also computes the largest length needed for these lines.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand*{\myDist}{1cm} % distance between consecutive oblique lines
\newcommand*{\myAngle}{55} % angle of said lines wrt horizontal, in degrees
% Distance between consecutive oblique lines, projected on the horizontal axis
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\horizIntervWidth}{\myDist/sin(\myAngle)}

% Length of the longest oblique lines we'll need. I add 10pt to be 100% safe
% with respect to rounding errors (the lines will be clipped anyway).
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\maxLength}{10pt + \paperheight/sin(\myAngle)}

% Number of oblique lines to draw
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\maxIndex}{
  round((\paperheight/tan(\myAngle) + \paperwidth)/\horizIntervWidth)}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
% Just to be sure we don't paint outside the page. :-)
\clip (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);

\foreach \i in {1,2,...,30} {
  \draw[black] ($(current page.north west)+(0,-\i)$) --
               ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\i)$);
}

\foreach \i in {0.5,1.5,...,60} {
  \draw[lightgray] ($(current page.north west)+(0,-\i)$) --
                   ($(current page.north east)+(0,-\i)$);
}

\foreach \i in {1,2,...,\maxIndex} {
  \draw[red] ([xshift=-\i*\horizIntervWidth]current page.south east) --
            +(\myAngle:\maxLength);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

This does *not* answer you specfic question, but can be adapted for you use with many other options built in. I have tried to set the defaults to your requirements (left in the vertical lines, but you can disable that by indlugin `draw=none` to the end of `Vertical Line Style` and `Vertical Line Style Alternate`.

[image]

### Notes:

- There are three differnt types of lines: Horizontal, Vertical and HorizontalSlant.
- The slant angle can be set via `\SlantAngle`.
- Each line style has a `\tikzset` to have an alternate style applied to every nth line and each has two lines styles associated with it: the main style and an alternate line style.
- The border is optional and can be disabled by setting `\MarginTop`, `\MarginBottom`, `\MarginLeft` and `\MarginRight` to `0.0cm`.

### Code:

```
%% Calligraphy Guide Lines
%% Peter Grill
%%
%% ---------------------- Note: May need to run this twice ---------------------
%%
%% --------------------------------------------------- Select Lines 
%% ---------------------------------------------------------------- Horizontal Lines
\def\VerticalSkip{1.0cm}%               0.10cm through 2cm
\def\UseAltStyleEveryNthHorizontalLine{2}%

%% ---------------------------------------------------------------- Vertical Slant Lines
\def\HorizontalSlantSkip{1.0cm}%    
\def\SlantAngle{55}%                    Degrees >30, < 60
\def\UseAltStyleEveryNthSlantLine{4}%

%% ---------------------------------------------------------------- Vertical Lines
\def\HorizontalSkip{2.66625cm}%     
\def\UseAltStyleEveryNthVerticalLine{5}%


%% ---------------------------------------------------------------- Select Margins
\def\MarginTop{0.25cm}
\def\MarginBottom{0.25cm}
\def\MarginLeft{0.25cm} 
\def\MarginRight{0.25cm} 
%% ---------------------------------------------------------------- Select Paper 
\def\Paper{a4paper}%        letter | a4paper | a5paper, ....
\def\Orientation{portrait}%% portrait | landscape
%% -----------------------
\documentclass[\Paper, \Orientation]{article}% Version 1.1


\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}

\pagestyle{empty}

%% Select the line style. I prefer using the second one here and using the output underneath
%% the actual paper as guide lines. The first is better if you want to actually write on 
%% top of the guide lines
%%
%% Few other options that can be applied here (last applied options override earlier ones).
%%     solid
%%     dotted,          densely dotted,     loosely dotted,
%%     dashed,          densely dashed,     loosely dashed,
%%     dash dot dot,    densely dash dot dot,   loosely dash dot dot,
%%     loosely dashed,
%%
%% Custom line styles can be defined also be specifying the on/off patter:
%%     dash pattern=on 2pt off 3pt on 4pt off 4pt
%%
%% To disable ANY lines use the draw=none as the last style.

%\tikzset{Line Style/.style={line width=1pt, densely dotted, gray, draw opacity=0.1}}
\tikzset{Line Style/.style={
    line width=0.2pt, 
    solid, 
    gray, 
    draw opacity=0.5
 }}

\tikzset{Horizontal Line Style/.style={
    Line Style, 
    solid,
 }}
\tikzset{Horizontal Line Style Alternate/.style={
    Line Style, 
    line width=0.2pt, 
    dashed, 
    draw opacity=1.0, 
}}

\tikzset{Slant Line Style/.style={
    Line Style
}}
\tikzset{Slant Line Style Alternate/.style={
    Line Style, 
    line width=0.2pt, 
    solid, 
    draw opacity=1.0, 
    red
}}


\tikzset{Vertical Line Style/.style={Line Style, line width=0.1pt}}
\tikzset{Vertical Line Style Alternate/.style={Line Style, line width=0.1pt}}


\tikzset{Border Line Style/.style={Line Style, thin}}


\newlength{\DeltaY}
\newlength{\TempLength}

\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\MaxHorizontalLines}{\paperheight/\VerticalSkip}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\TanSlantAngle}{tan(\SlantAngle)}
\pgfmathsetlength{\DeltaY}{\HorizontalSlantSkip*\TanSlantAngle}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\MaxSlantLinesX}{\paperwidth/\HorizontalSlantSkip}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\MaxSlantLinesY}{\paperheight/\DeltaY}

\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\MaxVerticalLines}{\paperwidth/\HorizontalSkip}

\newcommand*{\SetLineStyle}[4]{% 
    %% #1 = style name to set
    %% #2 = default line style
    %% #3 = line number
    %% #4 = which lines get the alternate line style
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Remainder}{mod(#3,#4)}%
   \ifnum\Remainder=0\relax
       \tikzset{#1/.style={#2 Alternate}}%
   \else
       \tikzset{#1/.style={#2}}%
   \fi
}%

\begin{document}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    remember picture, 
    overlay, 
    shift=(current page.south west),% So that (0,0) is south west of paper
]
   %% Clip to create the border
   \clip (\MarginLeft,\MarginBottom) rectangle 
         (\paperwidth-\MarginRight,\paperheight-\MarginTop);

   \foreach \y in {1,...,\MaxHorizontalLines} {% Horizontal guide lines
       \SetLineStyle
           {This Horizontal Line Style}{Horizontal Line Style}
           {\y}{\UseAltStyleEveryNthHorizontalLine}

       \begin{scope}[yshift=-\MarginTop]
           \draw[This Horizontal Line Style] 
               (0pt,\paperheight-\y*\VerticalSkip) -- (\paperwidth,\paperheight-\y*\VerticalSkip) 
           ;
       \end{scope}
   }

   \foreach \x in {1,...,\MaxVerticalLines} {% Vertical guide lines
       \SetLineStyle
           {This Vertical Line Style}{Vertical Line Style}
           {\x}{\UseAltStyleEveryNthVerticalLine}

       \begin{scope}[xshift=\MarginLeft]
           \draw[This Vertical Line Style] 
               (\x*\HorizontalSkip,0pt) -- (\x*\HorizontalSkip,\paperheight) 
           ;
       \end{scope}
   }

   \pgfmathsetlength{\TempLength}{\paperwidth*\TanSlantAngle}
   \foreach \x in {0,...,\MaxSlantLinesX} {% Slant Lines starting along bottom of page
       \SetLineStyle
           {This Slant Line Style}{Slant Line Style}
           {\x}{\UseAltStyleEveryNthSlantLine}

       \draw[This Slant Line Style] 
           (\x*\HorizontalSlantSkip,0pt) -- ++(\paperwidth,\TempLength)
       ;
   }

   \foreach \y in {1,...,\MaxSlantLinesY} {% Slant Lines starting along left of page
       \SetLineStyle
           {This Slant Line Style}{Slant Line Style}
           {\y}{\UseAltStyleEveryNthSlantLine}

       \draw[This Slant Line Style] 
           (0pt,\y*\DeltaY) -- ++(\paperwidth,\TempLength)
       ;
   }

   %% Draw border
   \draw [Border Line Style]
         (\MarginLeft,\MarginBottom) rectangle 
         (\paperwidth-\MarginRight,\paperheight-\MarginTop);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Another solution without `calc`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} %do not include "draft" in order to render pictures
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]

\foreach \i in {1,2,3,...,30}{
    \draw[black] ([yshift=-\i cm]current page.north west) -- ++(0:\paperwidth);}

\foreach \i in {0.5,1.5,2.5,...,60}{
    \draw[lightgray] ([yshift=-\i cm]current page.north west) -- ++(0:\paperwidth);}

\foreach \i in {1,2,3,...,60}{
    \draw[red] ([xshift=\i cm]current page.north west) -- ++(235:2*\paperheight);}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here is an effort with [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) wrapped up in `luamplib`.  You can compile this with `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    numeric r, u, v;
    r = 55; % angle of lines (to horizontal)
    u = 1cm; % horizontal spacing
    v = 5mm; % vertical spacing

    color base, mid, slant;
    base = 1/4 white;
    mid = 3/4 white;
    slant = 3/4[red, white];

    drawoptions(withpen pencircle scaled 1/4);
    for x = -60 upto 60:  
        draw (left--right) scaled 80cm rotated r shifted (x * u, 0) withcolor slant;
    endfor
    for y = -30 upto 30:
        draw (left--right) scaled 20cm shifted (0, y * 5mm) withcolor if odd y: mid else: base fi;
    endfor
    clip currentpicture to unitsquare shifted -(1/2, 1/2) xscaled 200mm yscaled 280mm;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

This produces a page like this:

[image]