# How can I create grid paper, where horizontal rules are thicker than vertical ones?

Tags: templates, page, grids, notes, paper

I'd like to create a weighted grid paper template. I'd like it to basically look like a sheet of lined paper, but with faint, equally spaced, vertical lines through it. I looked into the [gridpapers](https://ctan.org/pkg/gridpapers?lang=en) template which has a set of templates but I could not figure out how to change the properties of the vertical/horizontal lines.

Comment: You could adapt the answer from [How can I draw angled lines in LaTeX to create ruled template for calligraphy?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/535666/4301) by eliminating the slanted lines via `\tikzset{Slant Line Style/.style={draw=none}}` and `\tikzset{Slant Line Style Alternate/.style={draw=none}}`.

Comment: Perhaps https://www.ctan.org/pkg/gridpapers or https://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphpaper

Comment: @PeterGrill Thank you for pointing me to this. I ended up adapting that answer. I think my result could use some cleaning up, however.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. As that solved the question asked here, you should post that as an answer and remove it from being part of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up w/

```
%% Calligraphy Guide Lines
%% Peter Grill
%%
%% ---------------------- Note: May need to run this twice ---------------------
%%
%% --------------------------------------------------- Select Lines 
%% ---------------------------------------------------------------- Horizontal Lines
\def\VerticalSkip{.75cm}%               0.10cm through 2cm
\def\UseAltStyleEveryNthHorizontalLine{2}%

%% ---------------------------------------------------------------- Vertical Slant Lines
\def\HorizontalSlantSkip{0.75cm}%    
\def\SlantAngle{55}%                    Degrees >30, < 60
\def\UseAltStyleEveryNthSlantLine{4}%

%% ---------------------------------------------------------------- Vertical Lines
\def\HorizontalSkip{0.75cm}%     
\def\UseAltStyleEveryNthVerticalLine{5}%


%% ---------------------------------------------------------------- Select Margins
\def\MarginTop{0.25cm}
\def\MarginBottom{0.25cm}
\def\MarginLeft{0.25cm} 
\def\MarginRight{0.25cm} 
%% ---------------------------------------------------------------- Select Paper 
\def\Paper{a4paper}%        letter | a4paper | a5paper, ....
\def\Orientation{portrait}%% portrait | landscape
%% -----------------------
\documentclass[\Paper, \Orientation]{article}% Version 1.1


\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}

\pagestyle{empty}

%% Select the line style. I prefer using the second one here and using the output underneath
%% the actual paper as guide lines. The first is better if you want to actually write on 
%% top of the guide lines
%%
%% Few other options that can be applied here (last applied options override earlier ones).
%%     solid
%%     dotted,          densely dotted,     loosely dotted,
%%     dashed,          densely dashed,     loosely dashed,
%%     dash dot dot,    densely dash dot dot,   loosely dash dot dot,
%%     loosely dashed,
%%
%% Custom line styles can be defined also be specifying the on/off patter:
%%     dash pattern=on 2pt off 3pt on 4pt off 4pt
%%
%% To disable ANY lines use the draw=none as the last style.

%\tikzset{Line Style/.style={line width=1pt, densely dotted, gray, draw opacity=0.1}}
\tikzset{Line Style/.style={
    line width=0.2pt, 
    solid, 
    gray, 
    draw opacity=0.5
 }}

\tikzset{Horizontal Line Style/.style={
    Line Style,
    line width=0.2pt,
    dashed,
    draw opacity=1.0
 }}
\tikzset{Horizontal Line Style Alternate/.style={
    Line Style, 
    line width=0.2pt, 
    dashed, 
    draw opacity=1.0, 
}}

\tikzset{Slant Line Style/.style={
    draw=none
}}
\tikzset{Slant Line Style Alternate/.style={
    draw=none
}}


\tikzset{Vertical Line Style/.style={
    Line Style, 
    line width=0.1pt,
    style=gray,
    dashed,
    draw opacity=0.5}}
\tikzset{Vertical Line Style Alternate/.style={
    Line Style, 
    line width=0.1pt,
    style=gray,
    dashed,
    draw opacity=0.5}}


\tikzset{Border Line Style/.style={Line Style, thin}}


\newlength{\DeltaY}
\newlength{\TempLength}

\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\MaxHorizontalLines}{\paperheight/\VerticalSkip}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\TanSlantAngle}{tan(\SlantAngle)}
\pgfmathsetlength{\DeltaY}{\HorizontalSlantSkip*\TanSlantAngle}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\MaxSlantLinesX}{\paperwidth/\HorizontalSlantSkip}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\MaxSlantLinesY}{\paperheight/\DeltaY}

\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\MaxVerticalLines}{\paperwidth/\HorizontalSkip}

\newcommand*{\SetLineStyle}[4]{% 
    %% #1 = style name to set
    %% #2 = default line style
    %% #3 = line number
    %% #4 = which lines get the alternate line style
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Remainder}{mod(#3,#4)}%
   \ifnum\Remainder=0\relax
       \tikzset{#1/.style={#2 Alternate}}%
   \else
       \tikzset{#1/.style={#2}}%
   \fi
}%

\begin{document}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    remember picture, 
    overlay, 
    shift=(current page.south west),% So that (0,0) is south west of paper
]
   %% Clip to create the border
   \clip (\MarginLeft,\MarginBottom) rectangle 
         (\paperwidth-\MarginRight,\paperheight-\MarginTop);

   \foreach \y in {1,...,\MaxHorizontalLines} {% Horizontal guide lines
       \SetLineStyle
           {This Horizontal Line Style}{Horizontal Line Style}
           {\y}{\UseAltStyleEveryNthHorizontalLine}

       \begin{scope}[yshift=-\MarginTop]
           \draw[This Horizontal Line Style] 
               (0pt,\paperheight-\y*\VerticalSkip) -- (\paperwidth,\paperheight-\y*\VerticalSkip) 
           ;
       \end{scope}
   }

   \foreach \x in {1,...,\MaxVerticalLines} {% Vertical guide lines
       \SetLineStyle
           {This Vertical Line Style}{Vertical Line Style}
           {\x}{\UseAltStyleEveryNthVerticalLine}

       \begin{scope}[xshift=\MarginLeft]
           \draw[This Vertical Line Style] 
               (\x*\HorizontalSkip,0pt) -- (\x*\HorizontalSkip,\paperheight) 
           ;
       \end{scope}
   }

   \pgfmathsetlength{\TempLength}{\paperwidth*\TanSlantAngle}
   \foreach \x in {0,...,\MaxSlantLinesX} {% Slant Lines starting along bottom of page
       \SetLineStyle
           {This Slant Line Style}{Slant Line Style}
           {\x}{\UseAltStyleEveryNthSlantLine}

       \draw[This Slant Line Style] 
           (\x*\HorizontalSlantSkip,0pt) -- ++(\paperwidth,\TempLength)
       ;
   }

   \foreach \y in {1,...,\MaxSlantLinesY} {% Slant Lines starting along left of page
       \SetLineStyle
           {This Slant Line Style}{Slant Line Style}
           {\y}{\UseAltStyleEveryNthSlantLine}

       \draw[This Slant Line Style] 
           (0pt,\y*\DeltaY) -- ++(\paperwidth,\TempLength)
       ;
   }

   %% Draw border
   \draw [Border Line Style]
         (\MarginLeft,\MarginBottom) rectangle 
         (\paperwidth-\MarginRight,\paperheight-\MarginTop);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

I think the code should be cleaned up (eg. I'd like to only have to specify one line style, not the main line style and the alternate line style.

Answer (score 1):

You will cannot do a customization of vertical and horizontal lines in a separate way using the gridpapers package because - in accordance with the implementation given in the documentation of the package - the developers used the instruction `rectangle` to define the grid, in that way, the best option to do what you want is doing something like campa.